# Copy/Traverse a Range using columns instead of Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy cell values from a Range into another Sheet. Below is my data to be copied.

```
TableA TableB TableC
Col1   Col1   Col1
Col2   Col2
       Col3
```

Below is the output I want (after copy). I need the data in two columns - Table Names and Column Names.

```
TableA Col1
TableA Col2
TableB Col1
TableB Col2
TableB Col3
TableC Col1
```

Below is my code. This will traverse the Range by each Row, instead of each Column. How can I change it to go column by column?

```
Sub Copy_Columns()

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:HJ185")
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = c.Value
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Sub CopyMyColumns()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")   ' Change the name of the sheet to copy from
    Dim oRngToCopy As Range: Set oRngToCopy = oWS.Range("A1:C4")        ' Change your range
    Dim oCol As Range
    Dim iC As Long
    Dim aRng As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")                              ' Change the name of the sheet to copy to
        For Each oCol In oRngToCopy.Columns
            aRng = oCol.Value
            For iC = 2 To UBound(aRng)
                If Not IsEmpty(aRng(iC, 1)) Then
                    .Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = aRng(1, 1) & " " & aRng(iC, 1)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    
    Set oWS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Copy_Columns()

Dim col as range, c As Range
For Each col In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:HJ185").Columns
    For each c in col.cells
        If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
             With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
                 .value = c.entirecolumn.cells(1).value
                 .Offset(1).Value = c.Value
             End with
        End If
    Next c
Next c

End Sub
```